# How to fetch file which drops in QML windows and drags from external?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a `TableView` in a desktop qml app which lists filenames which the user will work on. The files have been selected by the user from a `TreeView` of a `QFileSystemModel`. The `TableView` is basically one column where the file name is shown, but in the model the full path is stored. I use an `ApplicationWindow` in my main.qml.

In addition to selecting files from the `TreeView` I would like to be able to drag and drop files from the file explorer/desktop into my application, so that after a drop the filename gets added to the model and is thus shown in the `TreeView`. How could this be done?

Comment: Can you provide some code for us to fix?

Comment: I would only need the filename and path to be stored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to be able to drag and drop files from the file
>   explorer/desktop into my application, so that after a drop the
>   filename gets...

Simplify the question as:

```
How to fetch file which drops in QML windows and drags from external?
```

Answer: [DropArea](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-droparea.html)

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    DropArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onDropped: {
            console.log(drop.text) // file path
        }
    }
}
```